# Event ID 6482 : Root cause?

Tags: sharepoint-search

Every Saturday, I have this error that pops up in my Event Viewer (SP 2013) :

> An update conflict has occurred, and you must re-try this action. The
>   object SearchDataAccessServiceInstance was updated by DOMAIN\user, in
>   the OWSTIMER (31458) process, on machine name SHAREPOINTSERVER. View
>   the tracing log for more information about the conflict.

It seems that this error is also linked to the fact that my backup crashes on that day

> Object Crawl-0 (C: on SEARCH_VM) failed in event OnBackupComplete

If I fix the error -> no problem.

Of course, you will tell me to clear the configuration cache, and I'll agree with you. Files are newer in the cache than in the configuration DB.

Fine, so be it.

My question is : how to prevent that behaviour from happening again ? I find that clearing the configuration cache every week in production, by manual or script means, is far from a solution but just a fix.

Somehow, something runs on Saturday and causes all this mess. Did you ever had the chance to dig into this ? Do you have any hints to provide ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems that an autoprovision process was occuring at that specified time, therefore interfering with the backup process.
Rescheduling it to another time seems to have solved the issue.